# Add Encoding utf8 to XML serializer

Tags: c#

I have this code to serialize:

```
 using (var writer2 = new StringWriter())
            {
                XmlSerializer ser2 = new XmlSerializer(Sheet2.GetType());
                ser2.Serialize(writer2, Sheet2);
                _sXml2 = writer2.ToString();

            }
```

It works very well but the encoding is utf16, how do I change to utf8, I tried with settings but apparently didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XmlTextWriter and specify the encoding there. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but please could you help me implement it to my code, i am trying and getting errors

Comment: Simply pass the XmlTextWriter that you created as the first argument to the serialize method. `XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(writer2, Encoding.UTF8); ser2.serialize(xmlWriter, Sheet2)`. Other than that, if you have specific errors, please post them for us to see

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `XmlWriter` class object which provides the `Encoding.UTF8` class object as part of the `XmlWriterSettings` class object to get the output you desire.

Have a look at the documentation for this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10y9yyta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx